# Can the maven reactor resolve module dependencies locally when resuming a build?

Tags: maven

In a multi-module project, where module_b has a dependency on module_a, I want to run the test goal only in module_b. Using the advanced reactor option:

```
mvn -pl module_b test
```

builds only module_b as expected, but it pulls the dependency for module_a from the repository rather than the module's target directory. If the install target has not been run for module_a, the dependency might be out of date. The same thing happens if I try to do the equivalent with the resume option, i.e.

```
mvn -am -pl module_b -rf module_b test
```

(Note that this means the resume option may not produce the same output as a full build, depending on the specified goals)

Is there a way to force the maven reactor to retrieve the module_a dependency from its target directory without rebuilding it?

Comment: I thought this was a non-question, and that things would have to go through the local repository anyhow. But I just tested a `mvn test` (i.e. not ran through to `install`) and a dependent project reacted to changes in its dependency. So, good catch, [stusrob](http://stackoverflow.com/users/872290/stusrob)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not currently possible with the built-in reactor, according to [this comment on the Maven JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4660?focusedCommentId=310089&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-310089)